# jquery dialog loaded empty, why?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

1. I have a main view (say with one dropdown), where I bound the view with model "TabViewModel".
2. In the main view I have a link button, upon click of that I need to call a jquery dialog and in this dialog I need to show the same dropdown (what I select a item from DDL in main view, need to show as selected here).
3. To get the value of selected DDL, we do $.post in below call and call the below controller method which load the partial view in jquery dialog.

   $(function () {

   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

   // Wire up the click event of any current or future dialog links

   $('.dialogLink').live('click', function () {

   var dialogId = 'uniqueName-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)

   var dialogDiv = "";

   // Load the form into the dialog div

   var data = $('form').serialize();

   $.post(this.href, data)

   .success(function (result) {

   **alert(result);**

   $(dialogDiv).html(result); })

   $(dialogDiv).dialog({

   /*options*/});

   return false;

   });

   });

   public ActionResult OpenReportDialog(TabViewModel model)

   {
     return PartialView(model);
   }
4. Everything perfect, but jquery dialog load with nothing, however we got correct html (**alert(result);**).
5. below is the partial view (OpenReportDialog.cshtml)
   @model TabViewModel

   @Model.FirstName (example)

Please let me know what wrong with jquery code, why Html is not rendered with dialog. Thanks!

Comment: one think I suspect, jquery dialog load in browser, then it will go to cursor and then again partial view code loop through and a HTML is generated, but not refresh with dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, here we need to do,

```
.success(function (result) {
 alert(result); 
 $(dialogDiv).html(result).dialog({
/options/});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your target dialog has no selector in it to point.

```
var dialogDiv = "";
```

Hence your jQuery Dialog doesn't show anything in it.

```
$(dialogDiv).html(result);
```

Update the above statement with

```
$("#Idofyourdiv").html(result);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: you mean partial view div ID, unfortunately this also not works. When I see the HTML that contains my partial view, it's include DIV also.... <div id="idPartial"><input type="button"/></div>...hence I thnik $("#idPartial").html(result); will not work..please suggest.

Comment: one think I suspect, jquery dialog load in browser, then it will go to cursor and then again partial view code loop through and a HTML is generated, but not refresh with dialog?